# JUnit @Category method annotation to override class annotation

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing

I have a bunch of integration test in many *IT.java classes.
To start I want to have all the tests categorized as Integration test so I annotate the tests with

```
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class FooClass
```

At the same time it would be great to categorize at method level those tests that we want to include in other categories:

```
@Test
@Category(RegressionTest.class)
public void fooMethod()
```

So that, and it makes a lot of sense, when I want to execute the integration test it will run all the tests. Also, with the same configuration, I would be able to run only the regression test if I explicitly run the RegressionTest Category.

But it seems that is the class level annotation which have prevalence over method level annotation. Then I only have two choices to accomplish my goal and they are not really smart.

So, my question is, there is any advanced configuration I could use in JUNIT to achieve the desired functionality?

Many thanks, I hope my point is clear and maybe shared!

Answer (score 0):

Since `@Category` isn't part of JUnit5 - Jupiter, I'm assuming you're using JUnit4. You can use `@suiteClasses`.